# Adding elements to a set , adds elements to all the instances of the object containing this set

Tags: python

Hi
I have created a List of Objects. Each object contains a Set. I want to update the set's contents for all the objects in the list. The code that i wrote to accomplish this is

```
class Player:
    name = ""
    cardsInHand = set()
    hasBid = False
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name 

class CardDeck:
    deck = []

    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(39) :
        if i%10>0 and i%10<9 :
                self.deck.append(i)

    def dealCards(self,player):
        cardIndex = 0
        for tempPlayer in player:
            for j in range(4): # since want to add four elements at a time
                tempPlayer.cardsInHand.add(self.deck.pop(cardIndex))
                cardIndex = cardIndex +1
```

in the main method I am calling the above classes with the following code

```
players = []
players.append(Player("Player0"))
players.append(Player("Player1"))
players.append(Player("Player2"))
players.append(Player("Player3"))

cards.dealCards(players)
```

The problem is that dealCards method adds the elements to all the sets of objects. Instead of 4 elements in each object's set, I endup with same 16 elements in each objects's set?
I am new to python, am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating class attributes.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name 
        self.cardsInHand = set()
        self.hasBid = False
```

Comment: This worked !!!. Guess I'll have to look more into class attributes. I thought this is same as variables of class in java and in constructor you only have to initialize them.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, are class attributes something similar to global variables ?

Comment: If the class is global, then yes.

Answer (score 3):

You've defined `cardsInHand` (as well as `name` and `hasBid`) to be class variables instead of instance variables; by defining them in the class body, you're defining them to be variables shared by all instances. If you're familiar with Java, they are essentially like static variables. To make them instance variables, you need to declare them in the `__init__` method, like so:

```
def __init__(self, name):
  self.name = name
  self.hasBid = False
  self.cardsInHand = set()
```